# react-select onChange, function doesn't run

Tags: reactjs, react-select

hey guys thank u so much if you help me to solve this problem

i'm using `react-select` package

i just want a simple scenario
The scenario is that when the user select a value, inside onChange  I have a condition and I want to call the handleDateChange function based on what value user selected.

you can understand more in the code bellow

i try to run this code:

```
const options = [
  {
    value: '1',
    label: '1',
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    label: '2',
  },
];

 <Select
    options={options} 
    onChange={(e) => {
      if (e.value === '1') {
         return handleDateChange(false);
      } else {
         return handleDateChange(true);
    }
  }}
/>
```

I try to test the code below, and it executed successfully! but that's not what i want

```
<Select
     options={options}
     onChange={handleDateType(false)} 
/>
```

the handleDateType function have alot of detial that's why i'm not put the code here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you create a function just to handle this conditions that you have. It'l be much easier to handle that.
Something like that:

```
 const handleCondition = (e) => {
    if (e.value === '1') {
             handleDateType(false);
          } else {
             handleDateType(true);
        }
        }
    
     <Select
        options={options} 
        onChange={() => handleCondition(e)}
    />
```